# vb.net mySQL Backup

Tags: vb.net, backup

[image]

[image]

Look this is the error !

Please help me my problem is why this sfd_Backup is always error and I already import system.io

```
sfd_BackUp.FileName = "matirexellesystem[" & Format(Now.Date, "MM-dd-yyyy") & "].sql"


If sfd_BackUp.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim file As String = sfd_BackUp.FileName

    Dim server As String = "localhost"
    Dim dbUser As String = "root"
    Dim dbPass As String = ""
    Dim dbName As String = "matirexellesystem"

    Using proc As New Process
        Dim newfiledb As String = sfd_BackUp.FileName
        Try
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe"
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-u" + dbUser + " --database " + dbName + " -r " + file
            proc.Start()
            proc.WaitForExit()
            MsgBox("Done!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            proc.Close()
        End Try
    End Using
End If
```

Comment: Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour].  `always error` doesnt help us much.  Would you take your car to a mechanic and say "its broke" and expect him to know what to do?

Comment: You don't provide us the error message that you are clearly receiving and we are left to just make guesses. Then why don't you add a space between the -u and the username?

Comment: Try with: `proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-u" + dbUser + "  " + dbName + "  >  " + file`

Comment: I cannot reproduce. This code works on my system. Without more details this is not reproducible.

Comment: see the picture in top

Comment: You still did not provide the error message!  There are words that go along with those markers.  Read them.

Comment: see again that's the error